# Django 1.7 is dumping all print statements at server start but nothing when the application runs

Tags: python, django

I'm having some troubles figuring out what's wrong here.. I'm trying to setup the logging for my django project, but I get all the debug messages sent out as soon as I start `./manage.py runserver`. Nothing happens while I navigate the website.

I've tried to isolate the logging problem by setting up in a very simple app. Same problem.

So I've also tried the very basic `print` statements, and I see the same behavior...

Here is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from architects.models import Architect

# Create your views here.
class ArchitectList(ListView):
    print('architect list')
    model = Architect
    template_name = 'backend/architects.html'

class ArchitectCreate(CreateView):
    print('create architect view')
    model = Architect
    template_name = 'backend/architect_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('backend:architects')
    fields = ['name']

class ArchitectUpdate(UpdateView):
    print('update architect view')
    model = Architect
    template_name = 'backend/architect_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('backend:architects')
    fields = ['name']

class ArchitectDelete(DeleteView):
    print('delete architect view')
    model = Architect
    template_name = 'backend/architect_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('backend:architects')
```

That's what I see when I start the django dev server :

```
$ ./manage.py runserver
architect list
create architect view
update architect view
delete architect view
architect list
create architect view
update architect view
delete architect view
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 08, 2014 - 13:49:03
Django version 1.7, using settings 'turigo.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

All the `print`statements are dumped here... ok. But now when I navigate the website to the different views, nothing happens...

```
[08/Oct/2014 13:51:40] "GET /admin/architects/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10643
[08/Oct/2014 13:51:43] "GET /admin/architects/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10956
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: That's because the `print`s are executed when the classes are created. You need to put them inside the view methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, anything defined at class level is always executed when the file is first imported. (That applies as much to assignments like `model = Architect` as it does to print statements: the assignments are simply executable statements themselves).

As parchment suggests, you need to move those statements into the methods which run when Django calls the view: since you don't have any, you can just do a basic override of the base `dispatch` method:

```
class ArchitectList(ListView)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('in architect list')
        return super(ArchitectList, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```